Writing Regex for handling optional floating point symbols at start of string?
I'm currently using a regex for detecting valid floating point numbers which looks like this:
/^[0-9]{1,10}(\.\d{0,3})?$/
I am able to match the following values as expect:
0
0.
0.1
0.12
0.123

I do however need to be able to validate and match the following inputs as these values can be parsed as a Number type in JavaScript.
.1
.12 
.123

I've looked at optional first character matching but so far I haven't been able to come up with a tangible solution. I think the fact that it's optional makes it tricky to implement

Can you show how you've tried to use optional character? Because that should work in your case. See here

^(?!\.?$)\d{0,10}(\.\d{0,3})?$ make all the digits optional with a negative lookahead should be okay

To match valid floating-point numbers, including those you provided (like .1, .12, .123), you can use the following regular expression:
/^(?:\d{1,10}(\.\d{0,3})?|(\.\d{1,3}))$/

EXPLANATION:
your original regex correctly matches numbers with 1 to 10 digits before the decimal point and 0 to 3 digits after the decimal. However, it misses one key case: numbers that start with a decimal point (e.g., .1, .12, .123).
To cover this missing case, I made two changes:
1 - Made the digits before the decimal optional: I wrapped the part that matches digits before the decimal in a non-capturing group (?: ... )? and made it optional with ?. This allows the regex to match numbers that don’t have digits before the decimal, such as .1, .12, and .123.
2 - Added an alternative to match numbers starting with a decimal: I added an alternative pattern (\.\d{1,3}) after a | (OR) operator to explicitly match cases where the number starts with a decimal point and has 1 to 3 digits after it. This ensures that numbers like .1, .12, and .123 are valid matches.

You could consider to also make the optional group non-capturing and even drop the group after the alternation, see maybe like this: ^(?:\d{1,10}(?:\.\d{0,3})?|\.\d{1,3})$

Good point! Switching to a noncapturing group streamlines the regex without affecting the match. all is correctly matched with both versions, but the noncapturing grp reduces unnecessary captures

To match floating point numbers, including those with a leading decimal point, you can use the following regular expression:
/^\d*\.?\d+$|^\.\d+$/

It handles cases with optional leading digits, optional decimal points, and digits following the decimal point.

In its current state this does not match 0. which is desired. But you can modify the quantifiers and change to ^\d+\.?\d*$|^\.\d+$  so it would work as supposed to (besides that it's not respecting the provided limits).
